# Extjs4.1 - How to make items inheritance layout parent

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I define a panel have 2 items look like **http://jsfiddle.net/BB8Vu/**

```
Ext.define('Example', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    border: false,
    alias: 'widget.example',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'Age',
        name: 'age',
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 100
    }, {
        xtype: 'timefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Time',
        name: 'time',
        minValue: '8:00am',
        maxValue: '6:00pm'
    }]
});
```

And i using that in another form. If that form hasn't layout then that's correct. But if i using layout like

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Form',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 350,
    url: 'save-form.php',

    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%'
    },


    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'first',
        allowBlank: false
    },{
        xtype: 'example'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

that's fail look like (width of items in `example` not inheritance layout parent)

[image]

How to make items of `example` inheritance layout parent. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend the defaults:

```
defaults: {
    anchor: '100%',
    layout: 'anchor',
    defaults: {anchor: '100%'}
},
```

see your [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BB8Vu/2/)

> **Note** that a layout config get only processed on a container and not on
>   a component because a component don't has childs

Comment: is that the best way to change? or change `Ext.define('Example', {` is better?

Comment: @freestyle Well you cannot inherit when you inserting something as child, you can only supply defaults to childs. Note that inheritance is for definition while defaults are for instances. The 'Example' is a class definition that may be contained (inserted into a container) or may not be contained (rendered to a dom node). There is now way that I would recommend you to read the layout from the ownerCt (if there is one) even while it is possible it is not the way you should design classes. In your case the layout is defined by the implementation so let the implementation handle it.